# If $a,b,c$ are positive integers,and $\cfrac{a}{b}+\cfrac{b}{c}+\cfrac{c}{a}$ and $\cfrac{b}{a}+\cfrac{c}{b}+\cfrac{a}{c}$ are integers then $a=b=c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b,c$ be positive integer,and $\cfrac{a}{b}+\cfrac{b}{c}+\cfrac{c}{a}$ and $\cfrac{b}{a}+\cfrac{c}{b}+\cfrac{a}{c}$ are integers, how to show $a=b=c$?

Comment: "Questions About Integers" would be a good name for a number theory book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are not all equal, there must be some prime $p$ such $a = p^i A$, $b = p^j B$, $c = p^k C$ where $A,B,C$ are each coprime to $p$ and $i,j,k$ are nonnegative integers that are not all equal.  Without loss of generality $i \le j \le k$ (otherwise permute $a$, $b$, $c$ appropriately) and $i < k$.
  Then $ b/a + c/b + a/c$ has $p^{k-i}$ in its denominator, and can't be an integer.

Comment: This makes it seem like we do not need both conditions $a/b+b/c+c/a\in\mathbb Z$ and $b/a+c/b+a/c\in\mathbb Z$. Is that true? [Edit: Ah never mind, we end up using one or the other based on how we permute $a,b,c$ in the "without loss of generality" line.]

Answer (score 0):

Let $a/b$=x, $b/c$=y and $c/a$=z

$x+y+z=k$ (As given)

$1/x$+$1/y$+$1/z$ = q

$(yz+zx+xy)$/xyz=q

By AM-GM inequality,

(yz+zx+xy)>= 3xyz.

Equality holds when all of em are equal(As the given equation is an integr)
x=y=z, Which implies a=b=c.